After update to EF8 from EF6 shadow foreign keys are not generated for OwnsOne method
After update from EF 6 to EF 8 and generating a migration ContextModel is affected.
Some of the primary keys stopped being autoincremented, foreing keys and indexes were dropped.
An example:
Classes:
 public class Car
 {

     public int Id { get; private set; }
     public CarGeneration Generation { get; private set; }
     [...]
 }

    public class CarGeneration
   {
       public int Id { get; private set; }
       public int GenerationNumber { get; private set; }
   }

Fluent API configuration:
       public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Car));

        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Generation, p =>
        {
            p.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        
            
            //------- I needed to add this in order to avoid removal of lines marked by #### in Context Model--------
            p.Property(x => x.Id)  
                 .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            p.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("CarId");
            //--------------------------------------
            p.ToTable(nameof(CarGeneration));
        });

Context Model
                b.OwnsOne("XXX.CarGeneration", "Generation", b1 =>
                    {
                        b1.Property<int>("Id")  ####
                            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()####
                            .HasColumnType("int");####

                        SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b1.Property<int>("Id"));

                        b1.Property<int>("CarId") ####
                            .HasColumnType("int"); ####


                        b1.Property<int>("GenerationNumber") 
                            .HasColumnType("int");

                        b1.HasKey("Id");

                        b1.HasIndex("CarId") ####
                            .IsUnique(); ####

                        b1.ToTable("CarGeneration", (string)null);

                        b1.WithOwner() ####
                            .HasForeignKey("CarId"); ####
                    });
                    

Why is that? What causes the need for more explicit Fluent API configuration?
